# Difference between "running here" and "running to get here"

Tags: difference

"I have been running here" and

"I have been running to get here"

Do they mean the same thing as in:  I am here now and I ran to get here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the first one is slightly ambiguous. It could mean that you have been running to get to a place, *or* it could mean that you have been running *in the place you are in now*, maybe for exercise.

Hope that helps!